# How to make KmlLayer hidden?

Tags: javascript

I added on a map KmlLayer. It works perfectly, I'm happy.
Now I want to make this KmlLayer hidden clicking on any button just using JavaScript abilities.
Which way I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

if you store the kml layer in a variable you can hide it using

```
kmlLayer[x].setMap(null)
```

then redisplay using

```
kmlLayer[x].setMap(map)
```

Attacth onlcick event to the areas or object you want which will call a function and hide the kml layer.